# How to make a CircularSlider in neuromorphic style?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create this CircularSlider, however, I have no idea how to.
I use sleek_circular_slider, but it doesn't have an opportunity to implement neumorphic style, I was thinking of using both [flutter_neumorphic](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_neumorphic) and [sleek_circular_slider](https://pub.dev/packages/sleek_circular_slider) together to reach this goal, yet I don't have any proper idea.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this package
[syncfusion_flutter_gauges](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_gauges)
with this [example](https://github.com/syncfusion/flutter-examples/blob/master/lib/samples/radial_slider/customization/gradient.dart)